# What's the shortest way of converting list of lists to a string, one inner list per line?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and I'm looking for the shortest way of converting that data to a string where every inner list appears on a new line.

Assuming my input list is:

```
l_2d = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I want my output to be a string (let's call it l_2d_str), so that if i `print l_2d_str`, I get:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: In your title, you ask for "pythonic"; in your first line, you ask for "best"; in your last line, you ask for "shortest".  One of those three is very different from the others, and often the opposite of them.

Comment: *"I know the obvious ways of doing it"* - what do you think those are, and what precisely is the problem with your current implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
l_2d = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

l_2d_str = '\n'.join(map(repr, l_2d))
```